# is there a terminal command to identify which partition my /home directory falls under

Tags: boot, command-line, mount, partitioning

I'm familiarizing myself with disk partitioning, in the effort to get comfortable un/mounting.  I'm working on my understanding of my filesystem hierarchy.  My os runs through an LVM.

So via my root, `df`

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          2959116        0   2959116   0% /dev
tmpfs                          597496     1892    595604   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 953054756 11539200 893033252   2% /
tmpfs                         2987460    86160   2901300   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         2987460        0   2987460   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                      721392   156200    512728  24% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523248     4736    518512   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          597492       16    597476   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                          597492     2740    594752   1% /run/user/1000enter
```

I'm perplexed why doesn't `/dev/sda3` (under which `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` is) pop up?

running `fdisk -l` and I get:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B4C74C49-9F61-4047-8B95-02FDFB5EF348

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    2549759    1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2549760 1953523711 1950973952 930.3G Linux filesystem
```

And I notice in my`units` I only have 1 sector which is very different from online examples and books I've consulted.

Finally, using `lsblk` prints:

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                    8:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                    8:3    0 930.3G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt          253:0    0 930.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 924.4G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   5.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom `
```

So this backs the idea that my os is part of sda3, not sda2

is there a quick command that I could utilize to find out what partition /some/directory is?

Comment: It's `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root`. What's the problem?

Comment: @muru `fdisk` threw me off. It conflicted with what I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83781/understanding-partition-table-with-sda1-sda2-sda5), [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/introduction-to-mounting-filesystems-in-linux/), and even [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGlRKz2PECg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**df /path/to/file**

and `~` is an alias for your home directory.

e.g.

```
$ df ~/
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7      174464052 160263260   5295428  97% /
```

Comment: Krikey! I should probably clear out some disk space!

Comment: thank you. eureka! those flags on `df`.  imo: ubuntu is a bit of a resource hog...lol